# Search for tool: Connection between two pages

Tags: mediawiki

Search for a tool, that will tell me if two pages are in any way linked to another.

For example: Is Page A connected to Page C or are they in different "systems"?

Page A consists [[Page B]]

Page B consists [[Page C]]

The tool should tell me, that Page A is connected to Page C in the following way:

Page A -> Page B -> Page C

Answer (score 0):

[Mediawiki's Standard API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links) provides this service.

> API Links :
> Returns all links from the given pages.